# The recent activity page is a bit chaotic on area51

Tags: discussion, area-51, activity-summary

I think it's because there's a lot of activity on a proposal (and way more if you are following several) but I cannot find any use to this screen.

Have you considered only showing activity on your proposed answers (comments, and edits) as it's than on the trilogy sites?

If I want to see new proposed questions I go to the proposal homepage.

**EDIT**: The new "Most Recent Responses" separation is way better

Comment: Finally we can discuss area51 publicly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be okay if there was more context to the activity events.

As it is right now, it's pretty much useless since the activity only specifies the proposal a user posted on, not the specific question. And I'm not clicking through 70+ updates every time I visit.

If the listing had the specific question title in there as well, that would be far more useful.

---

**UPDATE:** This suggestion has been implemented! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been addressed - the specific question with recent activity is now listed, rather than just the Site Proposal name.