# Area 51 responses page seems noisy

Tags: discussion, area-51, responses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The recent activity page is a bit chaotic on area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52021/the-recent-activity-page-is-a-bit-chaotic-on-area51)

I'm following four proposals on Area 51, and page seems VERY noisy.  I get notifications about all new questions, and all new comments, which really clutters up the page.  Is there some way this could be narrowed down?

Comment: Yes, please.  I only need to see my responses.